# Is there really no way to hook into the reset event of an Ext.js component?

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I reset a form in Ext.js it resets every child component, but the only events fired are `invalid` and `valid`. It seems a bit "hacky" to hook them to handle the clearing of a value, is there no other way?
The "problem domain" is that I am writing a plugin to create dependent comboboxes:

```
Ext.plugins.combobox.DependsOn = function(dependsOn) {
    function init() {
        var cb = this,
            parent = Ext.getCmp(dependsOn);

        parent.on("disable", function() {
            cb.clearValue();
            cb.disable();
        });

        parent.on("select", function() {
            cb.disable(); // dependents will be disabled
            cb.clearValue();

            cb.getStore().load();
            cb.enable();
        });

    }
    return {
        init: function(cb) {
            cb.afterRender = cb.afterRender.createSequence(init);
        }
    }
};
```

This works well until I call `form.reset()` at which point the comboboxes remain enabled but empty. I'd like to be able to hook some `reset` event and there disable and enable my top component to cascade a disabled state downwards. Alas, it seems impossible but I hope someone has a smart answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "parent" is an Ext.form.Field, you could use createSequence on parent.reset.

```
parent.reset = parent.reset.createSequence(function(){
    //here, do what you would have done with parent.on('reset', ...)
});
```

Comment: ah, yes. I didn't think of that. It does feel a bit like a hack, but I suppose it is the only way to accomplish what I asked for. Thanks!